# Veracode CWE ID 404 Improper Resource Shutdown or Release

Tags: java, android, veracode, secure-coding

I have this code:

```
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            final String fileName = getFileName();
            File propertiesFile=new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
            fw = new FileWriter(propertiesFile);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(s);
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }finally{
            if(bw != null){
                bw.close();
            }
            if(fw != null){
                fw.close();
            }
            if(bw != null){
                bw.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Veracode detected a flaw (Improper Resource Shutdown or Release ) on this line **bw.write(s);**
How to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using try finally fix the flaw, and inside finally close the BufferedWriter and the FileWriter

```
   try {
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        final String fileName = getFileName();
        File propertiesFile=new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
        fw = new FileWriter(propertiesFile);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(s);
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);

    }finally{
        if(bw != null){
            bw.close();
        }
        if(fw != null){
            fw.close();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try-with-resources starting java 7

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(propertiesFile);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)){
    ......

}catch (Exception e){}
```